# Docker push getting error EOF to private repository

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to push images to repo private, but it's getting error below. Before, it was working, but idk what happened...

```
PS C:\Users\user\aplication> docker push registry.apprepo.app/app:1.22.3 
The push refers to repository [registry.apprepo.app/app]
f4ca70ea751f: Layer already exists
05e4cd1b24c1: Pushed 
1ed92f7e8e52: Pushed
f9cb3f1f1d3d: Layer already exists
f0fb842dea41: Layer already exists
c1cd5c8c68ef: Layer already exists
1d54586a1706: Layer already exists
1003ff723696: Layer already exists
f1417ff83b31: Layer already exists
Patch "http://registry.apprepo.app/v2/app/blobs/uploads/f3666007-df22-456e-b15d-094d0317e166": EOF
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14 as build-stage

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

ARG target_env

RUN npm install -g gulp-cli \
    && npm install \
    && npm run build:$target_env

FROM nginx:1.23.4-alpine-slim as deploy-stage

COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY --from=build-stage /app/nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY --from=build-stage /app/scripts/config.env.sh ./config.env.sh

CMD  chmod +x config.env.sh && ./config.env.sh
```

Docker Compose

```
version: '3'

services:

  app:
    image: registry.apprepo.app/app:${APP_VERSION}
    build:
      context: ./
      args:
        target_env: docker
    env_file:
      - docker/.env
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
```

I've try:

```
docker builder prune -af
```

but it not pushing yet.
I'll appreciate for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out where the problem might be, actually the problem is in NGINX, using the alpine image.

I decided to move the image to Ubuntu, using NGINX 18.04. That worked.